# Access ng-model value in external js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, angularjs-scope

I need to save ng-model value in string format and use it in an external js.Below is the code. I'm not able to save it in a string format.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('appNew', []);
    app.controller('controllerNew', function($scope) {
      $scope.dataSet = ["A", "B", "C"];
      $scope.selectColor = null;
      //var colorString = "A,Green:B,Green:C,Red";
    });
    /* Below function getValues() is in external file. 
    I just need to pass selected dropdown from angular JS 
    to this below code in string format as shown below*/
    function getValues() {
    var colorString = "A,Green:B,Green:C,Red";
            colorString = colorString.split(":");
            var lengthColorString = colorString.length;
            var colorStringRed = [];
            var colorStringBlue = [];
            var colorStringGreen = [];
            for (i = 0; i < lengthColorString; i++) {
                var group = colorString[i].split(",");
                switch (group[1]) {
                    case "Red":
                        colorStringRed.push(group[0]);
                        break;
                    case "Blue":
                        colorStringBlue.push(group[0]);
                        break;
                    case "Green":
                        colorStringGreen.push(group[0]);
                }
            }
           alert(colorStringRed);
           alert(colorStringBlue);
           alert(colorStringGreen);
    };
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="appNew">
  <table class="table TableOne" ng-controller="controllerNew">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Serial</th>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>Dropdown</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="data in dataSet">
        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
        <td>{{data}}</td>
        <td>
          <select ng-model="$parent.selectColor[data]">
            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="Green">Green</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>{{selectColor}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <button onclick="getValues()">Alert Values</button>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

here $scope.dataSet could be of any length for example ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"].
Is there a way to convert value in scope to string format?
Below is the Plunker link:
https://plnkr.co/edit/2MdwoWpu6MGrt2rA61io?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop through each item in the array and [concat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp) to build a single string of all the items starting with the first item.

Comment: if i try accessing $scope.selectColor inside the controller , i always get null..

Comment: You've set $scope.selectColor to null and you don't have any code to update it.

Comment: ng-model="$parent.selectColor[data]" saves the value in selectColor..you can check using {{selectColor}}..check the plnker i have added..what my concern is how do i store this in a variable as string so that i can use it in external js